# Native Tizen 3.0 watchface critical error. Treat: 2

Tags: tizen, watchface

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3krR3.png)

Hello everyone. I have a question. 
I develop Tizen 3.0 native app in Tizen Studio with "C". It is a watchface with routines for measuring user's activity.

Previously this app was as a package of service app and watchface perfectly running on tizen 2.3.2. After update to tizen 3.0 the package just stoped launching. When I combined the service routines with a watchface the app start working again, but after a period of time of running, I got the system notification that app consumes a lot of power, which I didn't got on tizen 2.3.2, and on tizen 3.0 the watchface crashes exactly on the time when the error (screenshot) appears in the logs. By the way this error is not appearing when Tizen complains about app's power consuming, I checked this.

And one of the interesting thing, that before this error another error with the same description appears, but the treat number is 0 or 1. And only when the treat number is 2 the app crashes.

I've searched information about this everywhere, but didn't find anything about this error.

The question is - what exactly the reason of this error? What causes it?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether service app running all the time consuming CPU power.
It should be designed carefully to make lower power consumption.

You may also use appcontrol to launch the service app.
Check below links:

1. https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/creating-native-service-tizen-wearables-part-2-service-launcher
2. https://developer.tizen.org/forums/native-application-development/service-combined-package-not-starting

Comment: thank you, but this does not work on my problem. I used the watchface and service_app. But because of I did not find anything how to make watchface and service app working together in one package I combined both apps just in one watchface project (all background routines inside the watchface app). And It started working fine! BUT... It can work for 1 hour or 10 hours, and then the error I described in my question is appeared. 
And I would like to know what exactly cause this error. Why it is appears chaotically.